# Logging in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight

I already wrote some light weight logging  code which would call server side every time I want to write a log and which internally uses Enterprise logging application block. Now, I'm in a situation to log a lot in order to find out a production bug which I can't recreate in Dev environment.If I call the logging service for all the activities to be logged , it would be a hard hitting on the server.  I'm thinking of some mechanism to write at client side.

Do you have recommendations for logging the errors and other activities at client side or with less number of server side hits.

I heard about CLOG,NLog etc. Please share your thoughts.

Regards,
Jaleel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they have a `IsolatedStorage` logger target. I would recommend logging client errors locally on that area.

The relevant class source is at:
http://entlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/90009#1698914